# Как частично округлить целое число в JavaScript без запятых

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Есть вывод числа, например 5 684 814, как его округлить до более ровного значения, например 5 685 000, везде пишут про округление дробных чисел, спасибо.

Comment: разделите на тысячу, округлите, и снова умножьте на тысячу.

Comment: cпасибо, сработало)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в Javascript нет встроенной поддержки такого.

Вот простая функция для округления `num` к ближайшему `n`:

```js
const roundTo = (num, n) => Math.round(num / n) * n;

console.log(roundTo(12, 5)); // 10
console.log(roundTo(13, 5)); // 15
console.log(roundTo(5684814 /* 5 684 814 */, 1000)); // 5685000 (5 685 000)
```

Comment: что-то не так с последним примером

Comment: Да, я каким-то чудом неправильно скопировал результат из консоли) Но функция работает)

Answer (score -1):

Можете сделать что-то подобное как вариант:

```js
function roundNumber(n) {
  const L = String(parseInt(n)).length
  const k = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(L / 2))

  /* k = 10 ^ (L ÷ 2)

  где L ＝ длина числа (в виде строки)
  */

  return Math.floor(n / k) * k
}

console.log( roundNumber(5684814)   ) // 5,684,814 -> 5,684,000
console.log( roundNumber(40)        ) // 40        -> 40
console.log( roundNumber(42)        ) // 42        -> 40
console.log( roundNumber(1200)      ) // 1200      -> 1200
console.log( roundNumber(1234)      ) // 1234      -> 1200
```

Число будет делиться на `k` (равный 10 в степени половины длины числа), округляться, и снова умножаться на `k`, чтобы вернуть прежнюю длину числа.

`parseInt` используется для того, чтобы предотвратить те случаи, когда `n` — это число с плавающей запятой (float), соответственно, сама запятая и числа после неё увеличат `L`, а это нам не надо.